# How to remove indent for fbox?

Tags: indentation

The following is my Latex code in Overleaf:

```
\noindent\large\textbf{Title}\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}   
\noindent\normalsize\fbox{\textbf{Theorem:} \normalsize 2 + 2 = 4}\\
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}   
\textbf{Proof:}
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

If you notice carefully, the box is indented even though I have used `\noindent`. Please suggest how I can fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Tray with `\noindent\large\textbf{Title}\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}%
\noindent\normalsize\fbox{\textbf{Theorem:} 
\normalsize 2 + 2 = 4}\\
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}
\textbf{Proof:}
\end{document}`. Observe `%` after first  `\rule`.

Comment: @Zarko, it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX puts space at the end of each non-empty line if the line doesn't end by multi-letter control sequence (spaces after such control sequence are ignored always). The spaces from end-lines are typically ignored in vertical mode. But it is not your case, TeX is in horizontal mode in your example.

At the end of first line you have `\\`. Space is inserted here, because it is not multi-letter control sequence. But the macro `\\` expands to `\hfil\break` and the space is ignored as discardable item after such `\break`.

At the second line you have invisible item `\vrule` with zero width. The line ends by `}`, i.e. the space is inserted after the invisible item. This is a space what you want to remove. Typical solution is to add the `%` at the end of the line.

Third line is similar to the first: the space after `\\` is removed as discardable item after `\break`. Fourth line is similar of the second. The space form the end line after invisible item is inserted.